# Why can System F1 a.k.a. λ → have kind `*`, but no quantification `∀`?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, types-and-programming-languages

In *Types and Programming Languages* by Pierce, on p461 in Section 30.4 Fragments of `Fω`

> 30.4.1 Deﬁnition: In System F1 , the only kind is `*` and no quantiﬁcation (∀) or abstraction (λ) over types is permitted.
>
> F1 is just our simply typed lambda-calculus, `λ →` . Its deﬁnition is super-
>   ﬁcially more complicated than Figure 9-1 because it includes kinding and
>   type equivalence relations, but these are both trivial: every syntactically well formed type is also well kinded, with kind `*`, and the only type equivalent to a type T is T itself

Is it correct that  quantification `∀` means universal types?

`*` is the kind of proper types, which are introduced on p442:

> The level of types contains two sorts of expressions. First, there are proper
>   types like Nat, Nat→Nat, Pair Nat Bool, and ∀X.X→X, which are inhabited
>   by terms. (Of course, not all terms have a type; for example (λx:Nat.x) true
>   does not.)

So universal types such as `∀X.X→X` are proper types, and thus belong to kind `*`. 
Why can System F1 have kind `*`, but no universal types, i.e. quantification `∀`?

But if System F1 could have kind `*` and quantification `∀`, then wouldn't it become the same as System F2 a.k.a. System F? Quoted from on p461:

> In System F2 , we still have only kind `*` and no lambda-abstraction at the level of types, but we allow quantiﬁcation over proper types (of kind `*`).
>
> F2 is our System F;

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can System F1 have kind `*`, but no universal types, i.e. quantification ∀?

Because "System F1 has types of kind `*`" does not mean "any types which have kind `*` in *some other system* (e.g. universal types) are allowed in F1".